# What is the "null" value of the Javascript FileList object?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, different types have different "null" or empty values. For example, the empty value for `string`s is `""` and the empty value for `array`s is `[]`. What is the analogous value for `FileList`? It's not `null` and I couldn't seem to find it by searching through the documentation.

Comment: Note that you can't check if an array is empty by comparing it to `[]`, since `[] != []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is empty, check the [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#Attributes) property. If it is zero, the list is empty, if it is one or greater there are files in the list.

```js
document.getElementById('process').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    // do something with files
    alert (`Processing the following ${files.length} file${files.length > 1 ? 's' : ''}:\n` + [...files].map(f => `"${f.name}"`).join('\n'));
  } else {
    alert ('Please select some files to continue.');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" multiple>
<button id="process">Process files</button>
```